# Changing Lagrangian for a system

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, string

[image]

Above is a very basic system with three different masses. There is no friction on the table.

The Lagrangian for the system on the left is

$$ L = (m_1+m_2+m_3)\dot x_3^2 + m_3gx_3.$$

While for the system on the right

$$ L = (m_1+m_2+m_3)\dot x_3^2 + (m_2+m_3)gx_3.$$

The fact the velocities of all three masses are the same and the distances between the masses are constant is used.

My question is whether it is possible to define one Lagrangian that changes over time in such a manner, instead of having to redefine the Lagrangian every time a mass goes over the edge.

Comment: Sure, use theta functions.

Comment: Use *Heaviside step function*s

Comment: The derivatives of the Lagrangian are the useful part, so defining a Lagrangian with theta functions would probably make your life more complicated. There's only a couple blocks, and you know the distance between them, so why not stick with the original setup?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

with:

$$T=\frac{1}{2}(m_1+m_2+m_3)\dot{x}_3^2$$

$$U=g \left( f_{{3}}m_{{3}}{\it x_3}+f_{{2}} \left( m_{{2}}+m_{{3}}
 \right) {\it x_3}+f_{{1}} \left( m_{{1}}+m_{{2}}+m_{{3}} \right) {\it 
x_3} \right)  
$$

where $f_i$ must be controlled during  the numeric simulation

With $L=T-U$

you get the  E.O.M.

$$
{\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}{\it x_3} \left( \tau \right) +{\frac {g
 \left( f_{{3}}m_{{3}}+f_{{2}} \left( m_{{2}}+m_{{3}} \right) +f_{{1}}
 \left( m_{{1}}+m_{{2}}+m_{{3}} \right)  \right) }{m_{{1}}+m_{{2}}+m_{
{3}}}}
=0$$

and the solution:

$$x_3(\tau)=-\frac{1}{2}\,{\frac {g \left( f_{{3}}m_{{3}}+f_{{2}} \left( m_{{2}}+m_{{3}}
 \right) +f_{{2}} \left( m_{{1}}+m_{{2}}+m_{{3}} \right)  \right) {
\tau}^{2}}{m_{{1}}+m_{{2}}+m_{{3}}}}+{\it x_{30}}
$$

**Simulation results**

the red points are the time where the masses are behind the edge.

[image]

---

Remark

you have to write a program that controlled the factors $f_i$, i don't think you can do it with the step function?.

Program that controlled the $f_i$

[image]

Comment: note that your solution is only valid on an interval where the $f_i$'s are constant (otherwise you have to change the offset $x_{3,0}$ in order to connect the two solutions). Regarding your last remark, you can take $f_i = \theta(x - x_i) \times \theta(x_{i+1} - x)$, where $x_1 = 0$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ are the initial distances of masses $2$ and $3$ from the edge of the table (and $x_4 = \infty$).

Comment: @QuantumApple the problem of your function is that you get a recursive equation $x=x(f_i)$ and $f_i=f_(x)$ maple can't work with this!

Comment: my bad, I am not so familiar with Maple and I thought that you were looking for a theoretical expression of the $f_i$'s. Nice answer!